# How to implement 3 tabs compose navigation app with the same behaviour with navigation components with multiple backstacks?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I searched and implemented Jetpack compose samples. I implemented the below navigation codelab sample too.

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab

I have a problem here. When i clicked something at the tab, we navigated to a composable and pıut that composable to the stack. When i clicked back, the previous composeable is shown.

In my navigation component app which is not using jetpack compose, for example say that there are 3 tabs : Home, Favorite, Settings. I clicked Favorite, Settings, Home, Favorite, Settings. When i pressed back button, home fragment is shown. Then, when i pressed back button again, app is closed.

In my compose navigation app, i do the same action(clicked Favorite, Settings, Home, Favorite, Settings). In order to close the app, i need to press back button 5 times. This is my problem. I want to have the same behaviour with navigation component. I want that when i clicked back button starting destination fragment should be shown, then, when i clicked back button again, app should be closed. How to do that ?

Comment: please add some code, and if you used fragments you did it wrong.
there is no need to fragments

Answer (score 2):

//tab sealed class

```
typealias ComposableFun = @Composable () -> Unit

sealed class TabsItem(val title: String, val screen: ComposableFun){
    object HomeScrenn: TabsItem(title = "Home", { Home() })
    object FavScreen: TabsItem(title = "fav", { fav()})
    object SetingScreen: TabsItem(title = "Setting"{Setting()}, 
}
```

//you can add your tabs here

```
@Composable
fun SectionTabScreen() {

    val tabs = listOf(
        TabsItem.Home,
        TabsItem.Fav,
        TabsItem.Setting,
        
    )

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    Scaffold{
        Column {
            Tabs(tabs = tabs, pagerState = pagerState)
            TabsContent(tabs = tabs, pagerState = pagerState)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Tabs(tabs: List<TabsItem>, pagerState: PagerState) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // OR ScrollableTabRow()
    ScrollableTabRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
//        contentColor = Color.White,
        edgePadding = 0.dp,
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
            )
        }){

        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
            // OR LeadingIconTab()

            Tab(
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = tab.title,
                        fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h6.fontSize,
                        )},
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TabsContent(tabs: List<TabsItem>, pagerState: PagerState) {
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, count = tabs.size) { page ->
        tabs[page].screen()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**have you tried using Accompanist**

// Pager

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.23.0"
```

// Pager Indicators

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pagerindicators:0.23.0"
```